# Yet another quantum-entanglement-gives-faster-than-light-communication question

Tags: discussion, specific-question, duplicates

I recently misread [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100816/whats-wrong-with-this-faster-than-light-gedankenexperiment) and wrote a nice answer for what turned out not to be the question at all. I then proceeded to look quite carefully for the question I had actually answered, and I found that we don't really have a question (or answers) about the specific scheme described in

- [The choice of measurement basis on one half of an entangled state affects the other half. Can this be used to communicate faster than light?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/100864/the-choice-of-measurement-basis-on-one-half-of-an-entangled-state-affects-the-ot/)

I therefore went ahead and posted it as a self-answered Q&A.

I know we have had a ton of similar questions, and we have certainly touched on it edgewise (as in e.g. [this answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/2209/8563)), but I could not find this specific scheme, which is otherwise quite a popular misconception about entanglement.

The closest related question, I think, is [EPR-type experiments and faster-than-light communication using interference effects as signaling mechanism](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/55028/epr-type-experiments-and-faster-than-light-communication-using-interference-effe), but this question (a) uses collapse and not measurement as a proposed method, and (b) is unclear and not particularly helpful for future visitors.

This thread does not serve any particular purpose, but I set it up to avoid long discussions in comments. If you have proposed duplicates, I would be interested in seeing them and discussing whether they are indeed or not. I do feel, though, that we need a nice, simple and understandable canonical question for this scheme.